# How to disable action controller caching for some views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some static pages in my project that i would like to be able to change time to time and dont restart server to apply changes.
What a right way to do this if  `config.action_controller.perform_caching` set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find myself to use standart IO library to read HTML code from local file and render it through `render` method. Because it is a static pages, i dont need to execute any rails code inside. It work for me well, dont know about performance, but should be fine i think =)

Answer (score 2):

By using the method [cache_store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Caching/ConfigMethods.html#method-i-cache_store-3D) you should be allowed to set a  [ActiveSupport::Cache::NullStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/NullStore.html)

So in your controller you may use something like:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 config.cache_store = :null_store
end
```

Note: I haven't tested this code, but it should provide you a guidance.

*EDIT* Since you're using partials, maybe you can use the [actionpack-page_caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching) either by setting `caches_page  :new` to only cache the new action or to set the cache dir to `/dev/null` with:

```
class WeblogController < ApplicationController
  self.page_cache_directory = '/dev/null'
end
```

Since it's a static content also I don't see any trouble on creating a cache on that pages, but you're the owner you should know it best!

Comment: Thanks for answer but it doesnt help =( Maybe because i use partials?

Answer (score -1):

Two options :

- Modify the key of the cache to expire it.
- call Rails.cache.clear in order to clear all the cache, it is the quickest solution but watchout, it will clear all your cache

Comment: Is it safe to do in production?

Comment: *Clearing the **WHOLE** production application cache* `!=` *disabling caching for a specific view* :)

Comment: It is safe to expire one key. Clear the whole cache : it depends on the time to generate it